# Choosing an Audio API

Tags: c++, audio, sound

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-Platform Audio API Suggestions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3753/cross-platform-audio-api-suggestions)

I have gone down this road a few times, and always decided to put it off. I am finally to the point I need to choose an Audio library and stick with it. I switched physics engines 3 times which caused quite a bit of wasted time, so I would like to be set when I pick an Audio lib. I will be falling into the "indie" section as far as licensing goes. Here is what I have so far..

FMOD - Quality Middleware, success has gone to their heads and it seems they did away with the indie license recently. Price range seems to go from Free - 3000$ - 6000$ which pretty much excludes this.

BASS - So far this is what I am leaning towards. Simple API, great feature list, and quite a bit more. The pricing structure looks somewhat similar to FMOD, but I will need to pull out the Euro to Dollar calculator, and figure out if the Shareware license would be applicable to Digitally Distributed Content.

IrrKlang - Pricing looks fair, features seem generic. Pretty much coming down to a battle between this and BASS. I have heard good and bad things.

The other libraries such as OpenAL, PortAudio, Audiere, etc. were considered, but I am looking for something more drag and drop rather than something I am going to be basically writing my own front-end for. I am curious though, I remember stumbling across another library or two a few months ago on par with FMOD/BASS/etc that were fairly new. No matter how hard I look now, I cannot find them. Hopefully someone here knows what they might be called.

Anyways, basically just looking for feedback from other member's experiences, thoughts, and so on.

Comment: Should be CW, please split out each API you list into a separate answer.

Comment: How is this different from http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3753/cross-platform-audio-api-suggestions ?

Comment: It isn't, but I'd say both should be CW.